# .Net Core web app get access to a service in GCP secured by IAP

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

We would like to run a .Net Core web app locally to connect to a web service that hosted in GCP. The web service is secured by google AIP, which means we have a authenticate first.
What we have so far is an oAuth2 credential (client id, secret).

Do you have any idea how do I get the access token by oAuth2 credential in my .Net Core app?
At this moment, we just want to run it locally.

Comment: You will get the access token by authorizing using google as identity provider. Check out this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: thanks @SlobodanT, but seems it's not working for me, as it's not popping up the login page. And I think what I need the most is a way to generate the token that to pass the IAP to connect to the web service via http request.

Comment: Did you get a resolution to this?